What is the radiation force parallel to a surface?
As light falls normally on surface of perfectly reflecting mirror, the expression of force is
$$F = \dfrac{2I}{c},$$
where $I$ represents the intensity. 
Also for oblique case (when light falls at angle $\alpha$ with respect to normal), the expression of force along normal is
$$F = \frac{2I}{c}\cos^2(\alpha).$$
However, I don't know which laws are valid for light (as a wave, here I'm assuming above expression using particle nature which can be done using momentum conservation and the fact that force parallel to $x$-axis is zero). Will force along $x$-axis be zero considering dual nature of light? And does force along normal change?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The photon can push real objects (e.g. solar sail) in the forward direction of its original path. I don't know though if any sideway/normal force (angular acceleration) is imparted due to the photon's polarization.

@Community here I am interested in knowing whether there exist any force parallel to surface when light gets reflected. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure. Here check out 'Solar radiation pressure'
: Pressures of absorption and reflection. It is specified that there IS a force parallel to the surface after reflection.

@Andrew Steane Sorry, I made a mistake in the expression of force which I wrote , but you corrected it !

I suggest you should think about this using just classical electromagnetism. That is, don't worry about photons: the photon description will not add any further insight.
The main thing you need to know about electromagnetic waves is that, for a plane wave, the amount of momentum $p$ in any given volume of the wave is related to the amount of energy $E$ by
$$
E = pc
$$
where $c$ is the speed of light. That's all you need to know! You can work out the rest by momentum conservation.
For example, if we have a plane wave approaching a surface at normal incidence, then the energy incident on an area $A$ in a time $t$ is
$$
E = I A t
$$
where $I$ is the intensity (power per unit area). Therefore the momentum arriving in time $t$ is
$$
p = I A t / c.
$$
If the surface absorbs the light then it receives this momentum. Therefore the {\em momentum change per unit time}, which is force, is given by
$$
f = \frac{p}{t} = I A / c .
$$
Also, the force per unit area (called pressure) is
$$
\frac{I}{c}.
$$
That's the formula for an absorber. But if we have a perfectly reflecting mirror then the light is reflected back with the same momentum it arrived, but in the opposite direction. Therefore the momentum change is
$$
\Delta p = 2 I A t/c
$$
and the pressure is now
$$
2 I / c
$$
as the question correctly stated.
Finally, let's deal with non-normal incidence. The energy hitting a region of area $A$ at an angle $\theta$ in a time $t$ is
$$
E = I A t \cos \theta.
$$
The momentum arriving has magnitude $E/c$ and direction $\theta$, therefore its components perpendicular and parallel to the surface are
$$
p_{\perp} = \frac{I A t}{c} \cos^2 \theta,
\qquad
p_{\parallel} = \frac{I A t}{c} \cos \theta \sin \theta.
$$
In the case of a plane mirror there is no change in the component along the surface, and therefore no force along the surface. In the case of an absorber, on the other hand, there is a change of both components and therefore the force is non-zero in both components.  To get the force per unit area just divide the momentum change by $A t$.
